# Add char to empty string C#

Tags: c#

Ive got an empty string s = "";

Ive got a char b = '0';

char b is in a loop so changes after every, I want to keep adding that char b to the string s,

For example, after the first loop string s = "0"
after second round s = "01"

In Java its simple to do that for an empty string with string s += char b;
Couldnt find anything like that on C#, is there an easier way than building a string builder or making a dummy string?

Comment: Use a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).  Concatenating to a `string` in a loop is a bad idea as it can cause performance issues from creating a bunch of tempory `string` objects.

Comment: is there no other way than a string builder

Comment: No "good" way.  And why are you so against using `StringBuilder`?

Comment: `string += char` works in C#, too; if you are having issues please post your _exact_ code.

Comment: Same code works for C# too.

Comment: @DStanley Never said it was required.  That's why I put good in quotes.

Comment: You are saying "in a loop". Then probably the source is a char[]. If so you can simply create a string from that array: var s = new string( sourceArray );

Comment: @DStanley I wasn't answering the question, just giving a suggestion about creating strings in a loop.  If I though `StringBuilder` was the answer to the problem I would have written an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 5):

What you describe works in C#:

```
string x = "";
x += 'Z';
Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints "Z"
```

Or in a loop:

```
string x = "";
char b = '@';

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    ++b;
    x += b;

    Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints "A", then "AB", then "ABC" etc.
}
```

However, you should use `StringBuilder` for efficiency.

The same loop as above using `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
char b = '@';

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    ++b;
    x.Append(b);

    Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints "A", then "AB", then "ABC" etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy, but not *efficient* (String `s` constantly *re-creaing*):

```
  char b = '0';

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    s += (Char)(b + i);
```

Better choice is to use `StringBuilder`:

```
  char b = '0';

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    sb.Append((Char)(b + i));

  s = sb.ToString();
```